# Kotlin type mismatch while passing in parameter

Tags: android, oop, inheritance, kotlin

I'm overriding a function in a parent class that takes a parameter of type Any?. I want Any? to be an instance of type Venue, so that I can pull out it's id, however, I can't override the function using `getModelId(model: Venue?)` because that's not how it's defined in the super class. What's the best way to make sure that for this use case the class instance of model is `Venue?` and I can pull out the data inside of it that I want?

```
open class VenueAdapter: ParentClass() {
    override fun getModelId(model: Any?): Any? {
        //here I want to be able to pull the id out of the Venue class instance
        return model.id

}

abstract class ParentClass {
    //I've also tried defining it with a type parameter fun <M : Any?> getModelId(model: M) but that hasnt' worked.
    abstract fun getModelId(model: Any?) : Any? 
}


data class Venue (id: String)
```

I've also considered

```
override fun getModelId(model: Any?): Any? {
    when (model) {
        is Venue -> return model.id
    }

}
```

but I'm not sure that's the best way

Comment: This violates the Liskov Substitution Principle. The users of `ParentClass` can pass anything and the implementations should be able to handle it. Your `VenueAdapter` is guaranteeing less (or requiring more if you want to look at it like that) than what it overrides, meaning a caller that used to work suddenly doesn't when you plug in this implementation. You might want to re-examine the design to see if there's a better setup.

Answer (score 1):

If it's okay to return `null` in case the passed `model` is not an instance of `Venue`, then you can just use a [safe cast](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#safe-nullable-cast-operator) and a [safe call](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls) as simple as:

```
override fun getModelId(model: Any?): Any? = (model as? Venue)?.id
```

Otherwise, either add your default value after the [Elvis operator `?:`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#elvis-operator), like this:

```
override fun getModelId(model: Any?): Any? = (model as? Venue)?.id ?: defaultId
```

Or fall back to an `if` or `when` statement that will involve a [smart cast](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#smart-casts):

```
override fun getModelId(model: Any?): Any? = 
    if (model is Venue)
        model.id else
        defaultId
```

```
override fun getModelId(model: Any?): Any? = 
    when (model) {
        is Venue -> model.id
        else -> defaultId
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make the `ParentClass` generic:

```
interface ParentClass<in T, out R> {
    fun getModelId(model: T?): R
}

open class VenueAdapter : ParentClass<Venue, Int?> {
    override fun getModelId(model: Venue?): Int? {
        return model?.id
    }
}
```

Comment: I think VenueAdapter should extends from ParentClass but using the type Venue. Something like this `open class VenueAdapter : ParentClass<Venue, Int?> {
    override fun getModelId(model: Venue?): Int? {
        return model?.id
    }
}`

Comment: Sorry, forgot to change that ;)

Comment: IMHO, don't pass a nullable instance to `getModelId`. It may evident that a null instance will return a null id in most of the cases. take benefit of kotlin nullability to model properly